# How to change SVN user password by himself

Tags: svn, passwords, webdav, .htpasswd

We have local SVN repo over Apache location with WebDAV.
Our passwords are stored in `passwd` file using `htpasswd` command.

In this situation only admin can add/change/assign a password to user using

```
sudo htpasswd /etc/subversion/passwd <username>
```

But we need to add possibility to change password by user-self, so after admin added new user - user would be able to change password to own.

Is there any ready or easy to implement solution to realize this feature? May be some CMS or other LAMP solution? Or CGI...

*Of course, every user should be able to change only his own password*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like submin would work for you http://supermind.nl/submin/about.html ?

Comment: I tried, but a lot of problems appeared:
1) i can't add theirs key like they say in http://supermind.nl/submin/download.html so i can't to instal it from repo
2) i downloaded sources, but they ask for python modules (python svn)

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a little Perl script which allow each SVN user change his password. [svnpasswd](http://www.teuton.org/~ejm/svnpasswd/)